# I am trying to create a virtual environment in python but getting error "No Such File Or Directory"

Tags: python, virtualenv

Creating virtual environment in Windows

C:\Python>mkvirtualenv py1
C:\Users\176226\Envs is not a directory, creating
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\176226\anaconda3\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\python.exe'

This path exists: c:\users\176226\anaconda3\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\
And I do have python installed as well
Can someone please help

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create virtual env using command: pip install pipenv

Answer (score 3):

> c:\users\176226\anaconda3\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\python.exe

The above path is of Python executable not the environment source file.

Assuming that you are using Python 3, you can follow the below steps to create and activate Python environment:

To create environment: `python -m venv path/to/virtualenv`

Example:

```
python -m venv .venv
```

The above command creates Python environment in current directory.

To activate the environment created in the previous step:

```
.venv\Scripts\activate
```

`activate` is the source script which activates the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-python-virtual-environment-windows-linux/ Windows section. If python is installed in your system, then pip comes in handy.